# How can I find out if an AudioBufferSourceNode has started playing?

Tags: web-audio-api

[AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) snippet:

```
var myAudioBuffSrcNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
// Schedules for playback, but doesn't guarantee that
// playback will start right away.
myAudioBuffSrcNode.start();
```

How can one find out if a node is playing? So that something like this can be done:

```
if ( isPlaying ) {
  myAudioBufferSrcNode.stop();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think .start() doesn't start right away? It should or at least within 3 ms (sample-rate dependent) or so at most.

Comment: Failing unit tests gave me that idea, but after your comment I re-read the docs. Got to give a better look at my tests now.

Comment: Let us know what you find out.  There could be a bug somewhere.